# Typing french quotes in Russian: what's the most right way

Tags: babel, russian

As far as I understand, LaTeX itself provides the following way: `<<quoted text>>`. However, russian babel package provides also this way: `"<quoted text">`. They both look the same in the output document but the first one looks nicer in the source code and easier to type but it seems like the second way is more right when you use `babel` (or why does `"<` even exist there). Can someone explain the differences between `<<` and `"<`? Is there any document that explains all the language specific sequences for Russian (such as hyphens, quotes and dashes, starting with `"`) and how they exactly affect the appearance of these punctuation marks?

Comment: I would recommend [`csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)' `\enquote` macro and friends: `\enquote{quoted text}`. For a list of language-specific shorthands like `"<` have a look at [the `babel-russian` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/russian/russianb.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference at all. In `russianb.ldf` we find

```
\declare@shorthand{russian}{"<}{\guillemotleft}
\declare@shorthand{russian}{">}{\guillemotright}
```

This means that the shorthands `"<` and `">` are translated respectively into `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright`.

When the Russian language is used, the output encoding is T2A and in `t2aenc.def` we find

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\guillemotleft}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{190}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\guillemotright}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{191}
```

which basically means: `\guillemotleft` typesets the character in slot 190 of the current font; similarly for `\guillemotright`.

Let's look what happens with a T2A encoded font; the default one is `larm1000` and doing

```
tftopl larm1000
```

shows

```
(LIGTABLE
   [...omitted...]
   (LABEL O 74)
   (LIG O 74 O 276)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 76)
   (LIG O 76 O 277)
   (STOP)
   [...omitted...]
)
```

The `tftopl` program decodes a TFM (font metric) file into human readable format.

Note that numbers here are given in octal representation; octal 74 is the slot for `<`, octal 76 is the slot for `>`; octal 276 is decimal 190 and octal 277 is decimal 191.

The ligature table says: when `<` is followed by `<`, print instead of them the character in slot 190. Similarly for `>>`.

There would be a difference if a T2A encoded font misses the ligature, which can happen, but is only detected by wrong output. No issue derives from space factor codes, because Russian `babel` sets `\frenchspacing`.

Just for checking, run LaTeX over the following file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen

\sbox0{"<qt">}\showbox0
\sbox0{<<qt>>}\showbox0

\end{document}
```

TeX will stop twice like for errors; hit return to go past the stop. The relevant part of the log file will be

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.1493+1.94397)x20.27283
.\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 <BE>
.\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 q
.\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 t
.\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 <BF>


! OK.
l.9 \sbox0{"<qt">}\showbox0

? 
> \box0=
\hbox(6.1493+1.94397)x20.27283
.\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 <BE> (ligature <<)
.\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 q
.\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 t
.\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 <BF> (ligature >>)

! OK.
l.10 \sbox0{<<qt>>}\showbox0
```

Note that hexadecimal BE and BF are decimal 190 and 191.

The output is exactly the same (apart from the annotation that in the second case TeX has done a ligature).

Well, a difference *can* be made. You might redefine the shorthands `"<` and `">` to do something different, for instance adding some unbreakable space after « and before » (as the French use to do). Such spaces could not be added with using `<<` and `>>` (at least, not automatically).